# CSS dots with border with :before and :after

Tags: css

The effect I want to get looks exactly like in the link. The problem is the way I did it is not perfect. When I enlarge the site (ctrl + scroll), the content doesn't look centered. The best solution is to use CSS :before and :after and I want to keep it this way.

https://jsfiddle.net/4a9c3p5q/3/

```css
div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  background: red;
}

div::after {
  content: "\00B7";
  color: red;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 2px;
  font-size: 70px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>Sample text.</div>
<div>Sample text.</div>
<div>Sample text.</div>
<div>Sample text.</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the dots aren't centered perfectly in the circle outlines?

Comment: Yes, exactly, they are not.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the circle element to be `inline-block` so you can easily vertical align it with the text:

```css
div.timeline >div {
  width: 120px;
  padding-bottom:35px;
  position: relative;
  /*to replace the line*/
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) right 9px top 19px/2px 100% no-repeat;
  margin-bottom:-2px;
}


div.timeline > div::after {
  content: "";
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:20px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color: red;
  /*to replace the circle*/
  background:red content-box;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div>Sample text.</div>
  <div>Sample text.</div>
  <div>Sample text.</div>
  <div>Sample text.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem isn't the code. Because I don't have any problems when I enlarge the site. You can use em or rm instead of px too.